# Accessing ActiveX control through web server

Tags: web-server, html

I have developed the ActiveX control & register with Common CLSID number .
using the CLSID number accessing the active X control on the internet explorer (as web page).using following object tag used in .html file

```
OBJECT id="GlobasysActiveX" width="1000" height="480" runat="server" classid="CLSID:E86A9038-368D-4e8f-B389-FDEF38935B2F"
```

i want to access this web page through web server .I have place this web page into the vitual directory & access using localhost\my.html it's working.
but when i have accessed from LAN computer it will not access the activeX control from my computer .
how to embed or download the activeX control form my computer into the LAN computer through web server

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just like Flash or QuickTime, you will have to install and register your plugin on each client before it will work.

You can nest several object tags, if the outer one is not executed, the inner object will execute. In the inner object you can put a notice where to download your plugin installer.